# Starting activity behind current activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Can I start activity behind current activity? I want to change Home activity (launcher) by my service, but current front activity is closed. How can I solve this problem? Can I change the activity stack?

Answer (score 1):

Well this all sounds like funny business, but I suppose, depending on the complexity of the activity that is in the front, you could try the following:

- Save state of current activity (if relevant for you)
- finish current activity
- start the "behind" activity with no animation
- start the activity we finished with no animation, restoring visible state

All in one fell swoop, and hopefully (graphical glitches aside) this would provide the feel of what you're wanting. I'd only do this out of pure curiosity though.

Comment: I cann't switch activity fast because the user will see the flashing of the screen.

Comment: then get creative. With no animations and doing all the above in a single method call, the flashing is probably due to delays in init. First make sure anything that takes time isn't run on UI thread, only sync at last second. Enable the bitmap cache bit on the root layout element, capture the bitmap, and draw that as background while things are re-initializing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not Start an Activity in the Background!

I also think you can not change the Stack, but what you can do is Start your desired Activity by an Intent from your Service. In this case it should feel like a "Start Activity".

By getting the context of the current Activity:

```
Intent serviceStartActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), anyActivity.class);
serviceStartActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(serviceStartActivity);
```

Comment: How start activity BEHIHD current activity?

Comment: your shouting actually helped me understanding... Why would you like to Start an Activity in the background? I do not see the sense in this. Thats why I did not understand your question in the first place...

Comment: I am developing launchers switcher. This program change launcher when changing screen orientation. I can change launcher by intent, but current front activity (user app, not launcher) is closed.

Comment: I still do not get the point. Maybe you want your Starting Activity to decide quickly to select a portrait or landscape launch?

Comment: I cann't switch activity fast because the user will see the flashing of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

An activty is in execution as long as it's on the top of the view.
And as soon as another activity is launched, the first one goes on pause and/or on stop.
So, i think you couldn't launch an activity in background, or BEHIND, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I want launch an activity in background.

Comment: Ok, but you can't: by definition an activity is a process on top of the view (so, not in background).
Maybe you should use a Service?